# Is using command binding or event handler a better approach to implement Close, Minimize and Maximize Buttons in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making the close, maximize and minimize buttons in WPF C#. I tried two different methods and both seemed to work with me but I just want to know which approach in general is considered a better practice for this kind of implementation.

Method one: 
in XAML:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute_1" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_1" />
    <CommandBinding ... />
    <CommandBinding ... />
</Window.CommandBindings>
       <Button Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}" Content ="close"/>
        <Button ... />
        <Button .../>
```

in C#:

```
     private void CommandBinding_Executed_1(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.CloseWindow(this);
    }
    ...
```

Method two:
in XAML:

```
<Button Content="X" Click="CloseButton_Click" />
<Button .../>
<Button ... />
```

in C#:

```
    private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: "Best practices" - are always opinion based. My opinion: consider third approach with Model-View-ViewModel pattern and using of data-binding. See [Simple Command Example in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview#simple_command)

Comment: If you are using MVVM (which I *highly* recommend), use the `Command` `Binding` to an `ICommand` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the close, maximize and minimize buttons are typically part of a control, or a template of a control, you could handle the `Click` event of the buttons directly.  There is no need nor reason to introduce any command bindings just to be able to handle the click of a `Button` internally in a control.

You could either hook up the event handlers in XAML or, if the buttons are defined in a `ControlTemplate` of a custom control, you could override the `OnApplyTemplate()` method of the control and hook up the event handlers programmatically as suggested here: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/.

Answer (score 1):

Button click handler is simple and fast (to implement). If you are sure you are going to use just this button to close your window - click handler is good enough. If however there is possibility you are going to need more than one place to close the window (for example - you are going to use "close" menu option) - then it's better to not spread the same logic over multiple places and use a command, because command has all handling logic in one place (`CommandBinding_Executed_1` in your case). Also, command has `CanExecute` logic so you will be able to automatically disable your close button (and all other "close" controls) in case window cannot be closed right now (with click handler you will have to code this logic yourself). Also, with command you can close your window from any control down the tree, even if that control has no reference to your window at all. This applies to "command vs click handler" in general, not specifically to the case with closing window where some of the above might seem a bit contrieved.